# AWS Elastic Beanstalk : Error creating an auto scaling group without vpc

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, elastic-beanstalk

I have the following error when I try to create a Node.js environment in Elastic Beanstalk :

```
Creating Auto Scaling group named: awseb-e-neymbigw5a-stack-AWSEBAutoScalingGroup-1QX6LF04LAXUF failed 
Reason: The specified instance type can only be used in a VPC. A subnet ID or network interface ID is required to carry out the request. Launching EC2 instance failed.
```

What is weird is that when I do the same configuration with another AWS account, it works. So this error may be related to my AWS account configuration.

Any idea to resolve the problem ?

Thanks.

Comment: Does clicking "Create this environment inside a VPC" within the "Additional Resources" section not resolve the issue?

Comment: It could resolve the problem but that doesn't explain why it doesn't work without a VPC.

Comment: Based on this [link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-vpc.html) there are a lot of limitations of EC2-Classic as opposed to VPC. I assume one of these features is required hence the error you're seeing.

Comment: The error refers to your instance type. So it's probably because you are using a t2 instance. t2 instances have to run in VPC: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/t2-instances.html#t2-instances-vpc-support

Comment: @CélineAussourd - thank you. Was spinning my wheels for the past 2 hours trying to figure out why my beanstalk was failing to launch.